# Automatically load new InfoPath template

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2010, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, microsoft-infopath

I am using InfoPath 2010 with SharePoint. I created an InfoPath form template which I published in a SharePoint library. I can then create new documents or edit documents by clicking on "Add new Document" or clicking on the document to change. This works fine.

If I modify the form template and open a document a message is displayed at the top of the form that states that there is a new version of the template and asks me if I want to download this new version. If I do so, everything is ok.
If I do not download the new template I will be using the old template which is saved on my computer to create the document. This can for example happen if a user does not see the message.
Using old templates leads to problems because some fields will be wrong.

Is there a way to force InfoPath to automatically download the newest version of the template?

What I want is a way to make sure that it is not possible to use old form templates to edit documents or to add documents.